# Javascript, Cycle trough 3 classes in a single td tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-table

I am using simple html and inlay js + css to create a simple site that just tracks wether a worker is at work or not (by simply clicking on a td with their name), thing is I never worked with js and after a day of reading documentations and looking up stackoverflow and w3schools, I can't get my code running.
My problem is whenever i try to click on a td the background color doesnt change and when I got a solution the whole table background color changed, but I want a single td at a time, can anyone help me?
so far i got:

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
var el
function colCell() {
  if (typeof event !== 'undefined')
    el = event.srcElement;

  elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  if (el.style.backgroundColor == "#E5F0F8")
  {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#0066bb"
    el.style.color ="#ffffff"
  }
  else if (el.style.backgroundColor == "#0066bb") 
  {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#ff00ff"
    el.style.color = "#ffffff"
  }
  else
  {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#E5F0F8"
    el.style.color = "#000000"
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    el = e.target
  }, true)
</script>
```

With this table :

```
<div class="contentSection">
        <table class="awht2">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="line">LCS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="colCell()" style="background-color: #E5F0F8;">
                    TestFarbe
                </td>
```

Consider the td and tr repeated a few times.

sorry for being so noob'ish this is my first project with js and html

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :). Are there errors in your JavaScript console? (F12, then console). Also, you don't need the `eventListener` on `window`. Remove the eventListener and also the first if-statement in your function and replace `el = event.srcElement` with `el = this`. That should work.

Comment: Heya, and thank you for your warm welcome.
Console spew out a single error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
    at colCell (AWHT_Testthing.html:17)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick (AWHT_Testthing.html:56)
but i guess this was there before i changed the function to your comment

Comment: According to the error, the function doesn't know on what element you've clicked (it doesn't know `el`). Does it work with my changes now?

Comment: To be sorry it doesnt work, with your changes of el = this and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some improvements here and there:

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
var el
function colCell(el) {

  elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  if (el.style["background-color"] == "rgb(229, 240, 248)")
  {
    el.style["background-color"] = "#0066bb"
    el.style.color ="#ffffff"
  }
  else if (el.style["background-color"] == "rgb(0, 102, 187)") 
  {
    el.style["background-color"] = "#ff00ff"
    el.style.color = "#ffffff"
  }
  else
  {
    el.style["background-color"] = "#E5F0F8"
    el.style.color = "#000000"
  }
}

/*if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    el = e.target
  }, true)*/
</script>
<div class="contentSection">
        <table class="awht2">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="line">LCS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="colCell(this)" style="background-color: #E5F0F8;">
                    TestFarbe
                </td>
                <td onclick="colCell(this)" style="background-color: #E5F0F8;">
                    TestFarbe2
                </td>
                <td onclick="colCell(this)" style="background-color: #E5F0F8;">
                    TestFarbe3
                </td>
                <td onclick="colCell(this)" style="background-color: #E5F0F8;">
                    TestFarb4
                </td>
                <td onclick="colCell(this)" style="background-color: #E5F0F8;">
                    TestFarbe5
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

you do not need to have a window event, you can pass `this` to the `function`.

Comment: Works like a charm exactly what i wanted, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i =0;i<cells.length;i++){
cells[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
e.target.classList.toggle('gray');
e.target.classList.toggle('blue');
},false)

}
```

```css
td {

background-color: #E5F0F8;
color:#000000;
}
.blue{
background-color:#0066bb;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentSection">
        <table class="awht2">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="line">LCS</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    TestFarbe
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Almost i want to cycle trough 3 colors like blue > green > orange

Comment: Tried yours now in my code, the snippet here alsmost works like i want it, but when i copy and make adjustments in my code it simply dont want to work

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event object with `colCell()`. Then use `window.getComputedStyle` to get the current back ground color. This will be in `rgb`. Convert this `rgb` to `hex` and then use the `element.style.property` , where element is the target from which event originated & property is any css property

```js
function colCell(e) {
  let target = event.target;
  // the background color will be in rgb . In that this snippet is 
  // considering only integers and replacing characters and 
  // special characters with empty string. Then using filter to 
  // get only the values which are not empty
  let x = window.getComputedStyle(target).backgroundColor.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ' ').trim().split(' ').filter(e => e !== "");
  let getHex = rgbToHex(+x[0], +x[1], +x[2]).toUpperCase()

  if (getHex === "#E5F0F8") {
    target.style.backgroundColor = "#0066bb"
    target.style.color = "#ffffff"
  } else if (el.style.backgroundColor === "#0066bb") {
    target.style.backgroundColor = "#ff00ff"
    target.style.color = "#ffffff"
  } else {
    target.style.backgroundColor = "#E5F0F8"
    target.style.color = "#000000"
  }
}


function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(229) + componentToHex(240) + componentToHex(248);
}
```

```html
<div class="contentSection">
  <table class="awht2">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="line">LCS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="colCell(event)" style="background-color: #E5F0F8;">
        TestFarbe
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have used [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb) fro rgb to hex conversion